# DJANGO: local variable 'usuarios' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with this.
When a record already exists, I like the data, but when not, obviously not.
How is this validated so that the template can be seen when there is no record of a post?

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FZ0a.png)

**view.py**

```
def MemoList(request, usuario):
    instancia = get_object_or_404(Empleado, usuario_id=usuario)
    lista2 = Memorandum.objects.filter(para_id=instancia)


    for usuarios in lista2:
        lista_de = usuarios.de
        lista_para_id = usuarios.para_id
        lista_asunto = usuarios.asunto
        lista_fecha = usuarios.fecha


    context = {
        "lista2":lista2,
        "lista_de": usuarios.de,
        "lista_para_id": lista_para_id,
        "lista_asunto": lista_asunto,
        "lista_fecha" : lista_fecha


    }
    return render(request, 'app/admin/memolist.html',context)
```

Comment: The `"lista_de": usuarios.de,` line should be `"lista_de": lista_de,` to avoid that error, though all you're doing is assigning the last item in `lista2` to the context, not sure that's what you're intending.

Comment: @mVChr: Even then there can still be an error if `lista2` does not contain any elements.

Comment: since they are passing lista2 to context they dont really need the other varialves... he can access it on template using forloop and getting the attributes usuarios.de, usuarios.para_id and etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def MemoList(request, usuario):
    instancia = get_object_or_404(Empleado, usuario_id=usuario)
    lista2 = Memorandum.objects.filter(para_id=instancia)


    for usuarios in lista2:
        lista_de = usuarios.de
        lista_para_id = usuarios.para_id
        lista_asunto = usuarios.asunto
        lista_fecha = usuarios.fecha


    context = {
        ...
        "lista_de": usuarios.de, # Your user dont exist here (seu usuarios ainda nao existe aqui)

    }
    return render(request, 'app/admin/memolist.html',context)
```

If you have multiple users you should add those one to one list and send it to the context

Example:

```
 lista_usuarios = []
 for usuarios in lista2:
    lista_usuarios.append(usuarios.de)
    lista_de = usuarios.de
    lista_para_id = usuarios.para_id
    lista_asunto = usuarios.asunto
    lista_fecha = usuarios.fecha
```

OR use your own variable lista2 that have all your users

```
context = {
    ...
    "lista_de": lista2
```